# Vue js Laravel axios POST 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-6, http-status-code-500

I've just created laravel Vuejs Project using Axios for call API.
Get Api is working well but When I am going to post my data, getting Internal server error.
I am using Resourse for for controller.
I just Create Api and get data by This:

```
axios.get("http://localhost:8080/vuelaravel/tasks")
         .then(response =>{this.tasks = response.data})
         .catch(error => console.log(error.response));
```

vuelaravel is my project name.
Its working well. But when i am trying to post data into my database its shown 500 internal error.

```
Here is my controller:
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Todo;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;

class TodoController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {

        $tasks=Todo::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(2);
        return request()->json(200,$tasks);
    }

    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $todo=Todo::create($request->all());

        if($todo){
            $tasks=Todo::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(2);
            return request()->json(200,$tasks);
        }

    }

    public function show(Todo $todo)
    {
        //
    }

    public function edit(Todo $todo)
    {
        //
    }


    public function update(Request $request, Todo $todo)
    {
        //
    }


    public function destroy(Todo $todo)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

And My ADD.Vue

```
<template>
<div>


    <div class="modal fade" id="add" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <input type="text" name="name" v-model="name" id="name" placeholder="Title Name" class="form-control" >
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="addRecord">Save changes</button>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return{
            name:'',

        }
    },
    methods:{
        addRecord(){
            axios.post("http://localhost:8080/vuelaravel/tasks",{
                'name': this.name,
            })
            .then(data => console.log(data))
            .catch(error => console.log(error))

        }
    }

}
</script>
<style scoped>

</style>
```

This is The Error:

```
app.js:285 POST http://localhost:8080/vuelaravel/tasks 500 (Internal Server Error)

    at createError (app.js:699)
    at settle (app.js:960)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (app.js:168)
```

I am using my csrf in Welcome.blade.php

```
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{csrf_token()}}">
```

Get my data by This Api:

```
    created(){

         axios.get("http://localhost:8080/vuelaravel/tasks")
         .then(response =>{this.tasks = response.data})
         .catch(error => console.log(error.response));
    }
```

Comment: check in ur network tab and see error

Comment: are you sure the url in axios is correct? can you do in "catch()" console.log(error.response) to show more details.

Comment: http://localhost:8080/vuelaravel/tasks  is user for get and post. Get is working but post is not work.

Comment: do you mass assigned already your todo model ?

Comment: i am nothing to assigned  in my Todo model. Just create a model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using the method create in your model, please make sure you had mass assigned in your model by putting this code above.

```
protected $guarded = [];
```

please read this docs [soruce](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#mass-assignment)

Comment: Thanks bro, you great. This is the different between problem solver.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`response($tasks)` method

```php
 $tasks=Todo::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(2);
 return response($tasks);
```